# Recodificar la variable "Edad" en factor. Agrupándola en 5 grupos diferentes, definidos previamente por los quintiles

Tags: r, cut

[heartdisease DATAFRAME](https://github.com/SANTONLA/MLDataR/blob/master/data/heartdisease.rda)

Quiero recodificar la variable "Edad" en factor. Agrupándola en 5 grupos diferentes, definidos previamente por los quintiles.

Para ello, primero agrupo la tabla por la variable edad.

```
DFheartdisease %>% 
    drop_na() %>%
    group_by(Edad) %>%
    count() %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    kable(align = rep("c", 2)).
```

2.- Calculo los quintiles de la variable. (grupos homogéneos de datos, cada tramo represente el 20% de los datos).

```
quantile(DFheartdisease$Edad,prob=c(0,0.20,0.4,0.6,0.8,1))
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

0%  20%  40%  60%  80% 100%
28   45   52   57   62   77

Es decir, el rango de edades va de 28 (min) a 77 (max). Un primer grupo de edad sería (28,45); un segundo (45,52)...

#Quiero recodificar los valores numericos como la edad, en 5 factores

```
DFheartdisease%>%(DFheartdisease$Edad
%>% cut(Edad, breaks=c(28,45,52,57,62,77), 
              include.lowest=TRUE)
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

```
**Error: Incomplete expression: 
DFheartdisease%>%(DFheartdisease$Edad
%>% cut(Edad, breaks=c(28,45,52,57,62,77), 
              include.lowest=TRUE).**
```

Parece que me falta algo en la expresión...¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `dplyr` puedes resolverlo en un mismo lote:

```
DFheartdisease %>% 
  mutate(fct_Edad = cut(Edad, 
                        breaks = quantile(Edad, prob=c(0,0.20,0.4,0.6,0.8,1)), 
                        include.lowest = TRUE)
  )
```

Con `mutate()` creamos una nueva columna `fct_Edad` con la recodificación en función de los quintiles establecidos.

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis esta mal escrita,

la manera correcta de usarla es:

```
DFheartdisease$Edad= cut(
  DFheartdisease$Edad,
  breaks = c(28, 45, 52, 57, 62, 77),
  include.lowest = TRUE
)
```